# TV and mount ripped out of drywall

Tags: drywall, mount

I was just turning our TV to face the kitchen and when I did that the two screws in the drywall on top ripped out, then we had to rip out the other two on the bottom to get the TV off, now there are four big holes in the wall where the TV was, and I don't know how to fix it.

P.S. I'm not much of a drywall guy so i don't know what to do...

Comment: screws with anchors ?

Comment: Welcome to DiY! Are there tears or bulges visible around where the screws were ripped out, or is the area still flush with the rest of the drywall panel? And some **photos** would help!

Answer (score 1):

Make a (much) bigger hole and provide proper support (framing lumber or 3/4" plywood) attached to the studs -  then buy a piece of drywall to make a patch. A large patch and a small patch take about the same level of effort to do, so go large. There are plentiful questions and answers on how to fix drywall here already.

If you're strongly avoiding drywall work, apply a large piece of wood that can be fastened to the studs on either side of where the TV mount was attached, that will both cover up the holes and provide a solid place to mount the TV. Paint it to match or to contrast with your wall as you like, it will of course be visible, unlike lumber placed in the wall behind the drywall finish layer.

Comment: I feel like we should have a canonical question/answer for "hang heavy stuff on drywall", preferably with the "use these funny anchors, they really work *so* well" downvoted and "big piece of plywood" upvoted. The problem is that canonicals are nearly impossible to find due to the design of SE.

Comment: Well, I see codidact is progressing, but a community to cover this subject area does not appear to be there yet. Perhaps it can be done better there...

Comment: I hope we'll get there eventually. It is a bit of a catch-22. Codidact won't attract a lot of traffic until it ranks high in search, etc. but in order to do that it has to build up a lot of good Q&A. But can't do that without a lot of traffic *or* some dedicated users. Problem is that in some topic areas dedicated/advanced users can come up with a lot of useful stuff. With DIY, I feel like almost everything is in response to someone's particular problem/challenge (which is fine, but it makes it harder to get started). TL;DR I haven't seriously pushed for DIY on Codidact because I just don't

Comment: see the volume of users to make it work quite yet.

Comment: Ask Different has a meta listing the known canonical questions - https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different - which can be added/edited by users as they discover or generate more. It's not perfect, it requires user know it's there [which makes it definitely a higher-rep hangout] but as there's no distinctly better way to do this on SE, that's what we have. Super User has a smaller structure - https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13883/a-better-way-to-find-duplicates

Comment: Maybe an idea for the keepers of this site.  Ubuntu forums as a thing that you type out your question and can use a search like function to see if it has been asked before.  You check out the questions from before and see if any are helpful.  I think it is automatic.

Comment: There are a list of similar questions that come up here, @crip659, when you type in your subject line. Problem is that not everyone actually looks at them, and with many beginners the terminology just doesn't match up well. I've got a list of canned comments that I copy paste on a lot of questions/answers when there are issues. I can/should keep a list of links to cannonical answers to various questions (like TPE's _great_ answer on Stab-lock panel history and fire-starting tendencies).